# How to speed up this ddply?

Tags: r, sqldf

I have dataframe about the similarity of pair of products such as:

```
   Product1   Product2  similarity   
   p1          p2         0.102
   p1          p3         0.221
   p1          p4         0.333 
   .....
   p2          p1         0.102
   p2          p3         0.201
   p2          p4         0.242
```

I would like to choose the top 10 most similar product for each product, such as

```
product.pairs<-ddply(product.pairs, "product1", transform, rank = seq_along(product1)) 
product.pairs<-subset(product.pairs, rank<11,select=c(product1,product2))
```

this worked when the dataset is small, but once the product number reach 30k, it is too slow...

I also tried on sqldf, to mimic the rank & partition, such as...

sql_top10<-" select a.product1,a.product2, a.similarity,count(*) as rank 
from productpairs a
join productpairs b on a.product1=b.product1 and a.similarity>=b.similarity
group by a.product1,a.simlarity"

but this even worse... Any suggestions?

Comment: Try adding appropriate indexes to your SQL query.  Search http://sqldf.googlecode.com for `create index` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

dt = data.table(your_df)

# fast sort by similarity
setkey(dt, similarity)

# pick (at most) top 10 most similar ones
dt[, Product2[max(1, .N-9):.N], by = Product1]
```